# How to duplicate shell command with date increasing

Tags: linux, bash, shell

For example, I get a shell script as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
hadoop fs -mkdir -p /user/hadoop-mining/SEARCH/2020-11-25/ | true
```

For the requirement, I have to repeat the date from `2020-11-25` to `2021-06-30` in that shell script.
AND it should be like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
hadoop fs -mkdir -p /user/hadoop-mining/SEARCH/2020-11-25/ | true
hadoop fs -mkdir -p /user/hadoop-mining/SEARCH/2020-11-26/ | true
hadoop fs -mkdir -p /user/hadoop-mining/SEARCH/2020-11-27/ | true
..., ...

hadoop fs -mkdir -p /user/hadoop-mining/SEARCH/2021-06-29/ | true
hadoop fs -mkdir -p /user/hadoop-mining/SEARCH/2021-06-30/ | true
```

SO could anyone help me and give me some hints.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `date` command should be able to format up the date, e.g. based on the epoch date in seconds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With bash and GNU date

```sh
d=2020-11-25
end=2021-06-30
until [[ $d > $end ]]; do
    echo "hadoop fs -mkdir -p /user/hadoop-mining/SEARCH/$d/ | true" 
    d=$( date -d "$d + 1 day" "+%F" )
done >> script.sh
```

It would be more "natural" to write `while [[ $d <= $end ]]`, but
bash does not have a `<=` string comparison operator, so we have to negate the opposite operator.

Answer (score 2):

If python can be used ...
Here is the solution

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

n = 1
day_count = 218

start_date = datetime(2020, 11, 25)
for single_date in (start_date + timedelta(n) for n in range(day_count)):
    print(f'hadoop fs -mkdir -p /user/hadoop-mining/SEARCH/{single_date.date()}/ | true')
```

Answer (score 1):

As an example:

```
#!/bin/bash

i=0
while [ $i -lt 9 ] ; do
    i=$((i+1))
    dt=$(date -d"2020-11-25+$i days" +%Y-%m-%d)
    echo "/user/hadoop-mining/SEARCH/$dt"
done
```

Instead of echo, use your `mkdir`; instead of `9`, use your own upper limit.

done

Comment: sry, I fixed the question whose latest date should be "2021-06-30".

Comment: Note that this assumes GNU date features that the BSD date shipped with MacOS doesn't have.

Comment: @Bowen, you can easily extrapolate from this example to get the range you want. This provides a valid solution, and even says "instead of 9, use your own upper limit." If you would like a script writing service you should negotiate fees in a provate channel...